# How can I call a class function from a click on event

Tags: javascript, html

I usually program in Java and when I add an event listener to an attribute in a class, I can call the methods from the class inisde the event. However in JavaScript if I use "this." inside the function, the context is "onclick" and if I don't use "this." I get an error that resetear is not defined. How can I access the attributes and methods from Calculadora inside the onclickfunction?

```
class Calculadora{
    constructor () {
        this.resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
        this.c = document.getElementById("C");
        ...

        this.memoria = "";
        this.a = 0;
        this.b = 0;
        this.operacion = "";
    }

    resetear(){
        this.resultado.textContent = "";
        this.a = 0;
        this.b = 0;
        this.operacion = "";
    }

    assignar() {
        this.c.onclick = function(e){ // Here I need to change some things about Calculadora
            resultado.textContent = "";
            this.a = 0;
            this.b = 0;
            this.operacion = "";
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ES6 `Arrow Function`:

```
class Calculadora{
    constructor () {
        this.resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
        this.c = document.getElementById("C");
        ...

        this.memoria = "";
        this.a = 0;
        this.b = 0;
        this.operacion = "";
    }

    resetear = () => {
        this.resultado.textContent = "";
        this.a = 0;
        this.b = 0;
        this.operacion = "";
    }

    assignar = () => {
        this.c.onclick = e => {
            resultado.textContent = "";
            this.a = 0;
            this.b = 0;
            this.operacion = "";
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Arrow functions pass the context of the outside scope (the scope they're defined in) into the function. Read more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this

Answer (score 2):

You can define the `onclick` handler using an arrow function:

```
this.c.onclick = e => {

}
```

Doing this way, `this` inside the handler is the class itself.

Arrow functions preserves the scope of this while `function` creates a new scope.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about that